# bootstrap 4 carousel - place controls in the middle, not at bottom

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I've have a carousel within a modal that is working fine. I cannot, however, get the carousel controls to be in the middle of the card (or, at the very least, in the card footer).  Here is where you can see the problem:
[Test Problem](http://steppingstonez.com/test/testmodal.html)

What am I missing?

Here is the css for the controls:

```
.carousel-control-prev, carousel-control-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 47%;
}
```

jquery 3.5.1, bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example in the Question try adding `!important` property as below :

```
.carousel-control-prev, carousel-control-next {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 47% !important;
}
```

Comment: I get something a little bit different - the controls are up higher (clearly not 47% from the top of the dialog box).  And even with a z-index of 99999, the arrows do not function correcttly.

Comment: @user1309220 Can you add simple example to your work (Minimal, Reproducible Example) in your question .. Please Beacuse your slides are running very Fast and I can't even test them Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry about that- it quickly got more complicated.  Here is a codepen to illustrate:

https://codepen.io/pixelcraft5/pen/VwPxEGm

Comment: @user1309220 Great! .. It is not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Give a position and measures to each class.

```
.carousel-control-prev {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 73%;
} 
.carousel-control-prev {
   position: absolute;
   right: 20px;
   top: 50%;
}  
.carousel .carousel-inner {
/* padding-bottom: 40px; */ }
```

[image: working example]